# Drawing homotopy sequence with tiKz

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I'm trying to draw the homotopy sequence of a Serre fibration. I've been looking for how to do it and I have found how to draw a "snake diagram" but it did not work for me writing this code:

```
    \begin{tikzcd}[cramped, sep=small] 
    \cdots \rar
  &\pi_{n+1}(B,b_{0}) \arrow[r]
  & \pi_{n}(F,x_{0}) \arrow[r]
  & \pi_{n}(X,x_{0}) \arrow[r]
  & \pi_{n}(B,b_{0}) \arrow[r]
  & \pi_{n-1}(F,x_{0}) \arrow[r]
  & \cdots
  \arrow[dl, phantom, ""{coordinate, name=Z}]
        \arrow[dll,
                rounded corners,
                to path={ -- ([xshift=2ex]\tikztostart.east)
                |- (Z) [near end]\tikztonodes
                -| ([xshift=-2ex]\tikztotarget.west)
                -- (\tikztotarget)}] \\      
  \cdots \arrow[r]
  &\pi_{1}(B,b_{0}) \arrow[r]
  &\pi_{0}(F,x_{0}) \arrow[r]
  &\pi_{0}(X,x_{0}) \arrow[r]
  &\pi_{0}(B,b_{0}) \arrow[r]
  & 0
\end{tikzcd}
```

Because I want to draw this:
[image]

and the code writes this:
[image]

Comment: Your chances for replies increase, once you add: a) the documentclass, b) the (obvious?) packages used, c) \begin{document}, d) \end{document} ... because this reduces many speculations and would be ready for copy&run ...

Comment: You need `dllllll` (six `l`s) because your target is six columns to the left.

Comment: Oh! thank you so much!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is solved by comment

Comment: I think it should be left open because there's an answer below anyway. The "close as solved in comment" was only done so these questions don't keep getting bumped up on the front page after all (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8775/250119; https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3640/250119)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is explained in section 1.2 of the [TikZ-CD manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/tikz-cd/0):

> The arrow target can be specified by a direction parameter, which consists of a string of characters `r`, `l`, `d`, `u` (standing for right, left, down and up).

Thus, you need to use `dllllll` because your target cell is one row *d*own and six colums to the *l*eft.

I've added a `snakey` key that finds the auxilliary coordinate on its own (with the `calc` library, we could have used `($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$)`).

The `\tikztonodes` are setup along a lineto segment so that the nodes work as if they were placed on this segment (that way, no `near end` is necessary).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\tikzcdset{
  snakey/.default=.5,
  snakey/.style={
    rounded corners,
    start anchor=east,
    end anchor=west,
    to path={
      [insert path/.expanded={(\tikztostart)edge[line to, path only]
                              coordinate[pos={#1}](@aux)(\tikztotarget)}]
      -|([xshift=2ex] \tikztostart |-@aux)
      --([xshift=-2ex]\tikztotarget|-@aux)\tikztonodes
      |-(\tikztotarget)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[cramped, sep=small] 
    \cdots             \arrow[r]
  & \pi_{n+1}(B,b_{0}) \arrow[r]
  & \pi_{n}(F,x_{0})   \arrow[r]
  & \pi_{n}(X,x_{0})   \arrow[r]
  & \pi_{n}(B,b_{0})   \arrow[r]
  & \pi_{n-1}(F,x_{0}) \arrow[r]
  & \cdots             \arrow[dllllll, snakey] \\
    \cdots             \arrow[r]
  &\pi_{1}(B,b_{0})    \arrow[r]
  &\pi_{0}(F,x_{0})    \arrow[r]
  &\pi_{0}(X,x_{0})    \arrow[r]
  &\pi_{0}(B,b_{0})    \arrow[r]
  & 0
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]