# Connecting nodes using more appealing lines styles

Tags: tikz-pgf

For more appealing arrows, I use the following line bending style codes to control how arrows are drawn.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, positioning}
\begin{document}
1
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
 -|-/.style={to path={(\tikztostart) -| ($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$) |- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
 -|-/.default=0.5,
 |-|/.style={to path={(\tikztostart) |- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$) -| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
 |-|/.default=0.5,
}
\tikzset{block/.style={draw=green, fill=green!15, rectangle, rounded corners=.5em, align=center, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm},}
\node [block] (aa) {aa};
\node [block, right=of aa] (bb) {bb};
\node [block, right=of bb] (cc) {cc};
\node [block, below=2cm of aa] (dd) {dd};
\node [block, right=of dd] (ee) {ee};
\node [block, right=of ee] (ff) {ff};
\path[draw, green, -latex, line width=.06cm] (aa) edge (bb) (bb) edge (cc) (cc.east) to [|-|] (dd.west) (dd) edge (ee) (ee) edge (ff);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip 1cm
2
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
 -|-/.style={to path={(\tikztostart) -| ($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$) |- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
 -|-/.default=0.5,
 |-|/.style={to path={(\tikztostart) |- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$) -| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
 |-|/.default=0.5,
}
\tikzset{block/.style={draw=blue, fill=blue!15, rectangle, rounded corners=.5em, align=center, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm},}
\node [block] (aa) {aa};
\node [block, right=of aa] (bb) {bb};
\node [block, right=of bb] (cc) {cc};
\node [block, below=2cm of aa] (dd) {dd};
\node [block, right=of dd] (ee) {ee};
\node [block, right=of ee] (ff) {ff};
\node [coordinate, right=.5cm of cc] (rright) {};
\node [coordinate, left=.5cm of dd] (lleft) {};
\path[draw, cyan, -latex, line width=.06cm] (aa) edge (bb) (bb) edge (cc) (cc.east) -- (rright)  to [|-|] (lleft) -- (dd.west) (dd) edge (ee) (ee) edge (ff);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the green drawing 1, the used styles make the line goes directly down from node cc, and to node dd.

In blue drawing 2, for a better looking arrows, I used additional nodes to the right of node cc, and to the left of node dd.

**Is it possible to define additional line styles** to make the line goes to the right before going down (instead of using an additional node to the right). Also applying the same concept for going left (instead of using an additional node to the left)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need to redefine some of you styles. For example, let's do

```
\tikzset
{
  -|-/.style={to path={(\tikztostart) --++ (#1,0) |-
                     ($(\tikztostart)!0.5!(\tikztotarget)$) -|
                     ($(\tikztotarget)+(-#1,0)$) --
                       (\tikztotarget)}},
  -|-/.default=0.5cm,
}
```

The above code leaves the first node and goes to a point 0.5cm to its right (default #1 = 0.5cm). Then goes first in vertical direction and then in horizontal (`|-`) to the middle point between the two nodes. Then goes first in horizontal direction and then in vertical direction (`-|`) to a point 0.5cm to the left of the second node. And finally it reaches the second node.

[image]

An example, leaving only the essential part of your drawing:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\tikzset
{
  -|-/.style={to path={(\tikztostart) --++ (#1,0) |-
                     ($(\tikztostart)!0.5!(\tikztotarget)$) -|
                     ($(\tikztotarget)+(-#1,0)$) --
                       (\tikztotarget)}},
  -|-/.default=0.5cm,
  block/.style={draw=blue,fill=blue!15,rectangle,rounded corners=0.5em,
                align=center,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{,}
\node [block]                  (aa) {aa};
\node [block, right=of aa]     (bb) {bb};
\node [block, right=of bb]     (cc) {cc};
\node [block, below=2cm of aa] (dd) {dd};
\node [block, right=of dd]     (ee) {ee};
\node [block, right=of ee]     (ff) {ff};
\path[draw,cyan,-latex,line width=0.06cm] 
     (aa) edge (bb)
     (bb) edge (cc)
     (cc.east) to [-|-] (dd.west)
     (dd) edge (ee)
     (ee) edge (ff);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and answer

Comment: @Hany, you're welcome!!

Answer (score 7):

This is a generalized version of [my other recent `snakey` key for TikZ-CD](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/670054)
and gives you a `-|-` and a `|-|` key which do a few things:

- They place the first and last kink in such a way that they are `snakey distance` away from the *the border* of the nodes (this means you don't have to specify an anchor explicitly).
- The argment `#1` specifies the ratio (w/o units) or the distance (w/ units)

  - between the borders or
  - between the centers (when `snakey from center` is set)

  where the main middle part of this path should lie.

  If you specify a small ratio (like `0`) or a small distance and activate `snakey from center` the path might intersect the node again (see last line of examples).
- The line is set up in such a way that `\tikztonodes` (i.e. all the coordinates, nodes and pics you place along the edge) are on the middle part of the whole construct.
- The line always starts in the opposite direction away from both nodes. That's what the `\pgfextra` stuff figures out and the `\tikzsnakeysign(X)` macros control.

One of those styles could have been defined in relation to the other by just doing

```
|-|/.style={-|-={#1}, rotate=90}
```

but this might lead to some side effects.

---

All the *path calculations* are done inside an `edge` which doesn't change the current path and does not “lift” the pen.

The `.expanded` is necessary since the above mentioned `edge` grab their own `\tikztostart`/`\tikztotarget` (which we will ignore) and we need to circumvent this.

The *path calculations* are necessary to find the border of a node without somewhere hard-coding the appropriate anchors (and having to figure out which one to use) but it also allows rotated nodes (where `.east` might not be to the right of the node).

Since your example only uses singular edges between nodes that aren't rotated, have well-defined compass anchors and are sized the same, none of the fringe cases are there.

---

Let me explain:

1. Finding the first and last kink:

   ```
   (\tikztostart)
     -- coordinate[at start, shift=(#3:<distance>))] (@auxs)
   +(#3:+1pt)
   ```

   This places a `coordinate` right at the border (`at start` = `pos = 0`) of `\tikztostart` (if it is a node) in the `#3` direction and then shifts it about `<distance>` in the same direction.
2. If the middle part should be in relation to the center of the nodes we simply use [`calc`'s *pathway modifier*](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#sec-13.5.3) to find `@aux`.
3. If the middle part should be in relation to the border of the nodes (orthogonally to the middle part), we need to apply the same “trick” as in 1. to find these other border points `@auxS` and `@auxT`.

   With this we can do the same as in 2 to find `@aux`.
4. From there on out it's just a combination of [`-|`/`|-` path operators](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#sec-14.2.2) and [`-|`/`|-` coordinate specifications](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.perpendicular).

---

I've removed the `block` style from the `ff` node to show how different settings affect the outcome of the line.

I've also added another small example showing the usage on a longer path where `|-|` makes up only a part of it while still properly connecting to the surrounding parts (hence my desire to hide all *path calculations* in one edge):

```
\tikz\draw[line width=3mm] (0,0) -- ++(1,1) to[|-|] ++(1,1) -- ++(1,1);
```

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\tikzpointdiff[2]{%
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointdiff{\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(#2)}
                            {\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(#1)}}}
\makeatother
\newif\iftikzsnakeyfromcenter
\tikzset{
  snakey distance/.initial=.5cm,
  snakey from center/.is if=tikzsnakeyfromcenter,
  snakey/.style n args={9}{
    to path={
      \pgfextra
        \tikzpointdiff{\tikztostart}{\tikztotarget}%
        \expandafter\ifdim\csname pgf@#1\endcsname<0pt
          \def\tikzsnakeysign{-}\else\def\tikzsnakeysign{}\fi
        \expandafter\ifdim\csname pgf@#2\endcsname<0pt
          \def\tikzsnakeysignX{-}\else\def\tikzsnakeysignX{}\fi
      \endpgfextra % hide calculation inside another path wo interrupting current
      [insert path/.expanded={edge[path only, to path={
        (\tikztostart)  -- coordinate[at start,
          shift=(#3:{\tikzsnakeysign(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/snakey distance})})
        ](@auxs) +(#3:+\tikzsnakeysign 1pt)
        (\tikztotarget) -- coordinate[at start,
          shift=(#4:{\tikzsnakeysign(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/snakey distance})})
        ](@auxt) +(#4:+\tikzsnakeysign 1pt)
        \iftikzsnakeyfromcenter
          coordinate (@aux) at ($(\tikztostart)!{#9}!(\tikztotarget)$)
        \else
          (\tikztostart) -- coordinate[at start](@auxS)+(#5:+\tikzsnakeysignX 1pt)
          (\tikztotarget)-- coordinate[at start](@auxT)+(#6:+\tikzsnakeysignX 1pt)
          coordinate (@aux) at ($(@auxS)!{#9}!(@auxT)$)
        \fi }]()}]% () = empty edge target, must be present
      #7(@auxs#8@aux)--(@auxt#8@aux)\tikztonodes #8(\tikztotarget)}},
  -|-/.style={snakey={x}{y}{right}{left}{down}{up}   {-|}{|-}{#1}},
  |-|/.style={snakey={y}{x}{up}   {down}{left}{right}{|-}{-|}{#1}},
  -|-/.default=.5, |-|/.default=.5}
\newcommand*\mytikzdiagram[1]{%
    \node [block]              (aa) {aa};
    \node [block, right=of aa] (bb) {bb};
    \node [block, right=of bb] (cc) {cc};
    \node [block, below=of aa] (dd) {dd};
    \node [block, right=of dd] (ee) {ee};
    \node [draw,  right=of ee] (ff) {ff};
    \path[-Latex, line width=.06cm]
      (aa) edge (bb) (bb) edge (cc) (cc) edge[#1] (dd)
      (dd) edge (ee) (ee) edge (ff) (aa) edge[blue!50, #1, dashed](ff);}
\begin{document}
\tikz[row sep=5mm, column sep=5mm, every odd row/.style=snakey from center,
  row 1/.style={font=\ttfamily, nodes={scale=3}}, column 1/.style={anchor=east},
  row 4/.style={-|-/.default=.75cm, |-|/.default=.75cm},
  row 5/.style={-|-/.default=.75cm, |-|/.default=.75cm},
  block/.style={
    draw=green, fill=green!15, rectangle, rounded corners=.5em, align=center,
    minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm}]
\matrix{                   & \node{|-|};         & \node{-|-};         \\
  \node{.5 from border};   & \mytikzdiagram{|-|} & \mytikzdiagram{-|-} \\
  \node{.5 from center};   & \mytikzdiagram{|-|} & \mytikzdiagram{-|-} \\
  \node{.5cm from border}; & \mytikzdiagram{|-|} & \mytikzdiagram{-|-} \\
  \node{.5cm from center}; & \mytikzdiagram{|-|} & \mytikzdiagram{-|-} \\
};

\tikz\draw[line width=3mm] (0,0) -- (1,1) to[|-|] (2,3) -- (3,4);
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: @– Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you very much. Looking forward for your update.

Comment: @Hany I've updated my answer. It looks daunting but I've tried to cover all my bases.

Comment: @– Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you very much for your update.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative by use of Ti*k*Z library `ext.paths.ortho`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{suspend join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm and 9mm,
  start chain = going right,
   arr/.style = {draw=cyan, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}, line width=0.8mm},
   box/.style = {draw=blue, rounded corners=0.5em, fill=blue!15,
                 minimum height=1cm, minimum width=2cm, align=center,
                 on chain, join=by arr},
                        ]
   \begin{scope}[nodes={box, on chain}]
\node   (aa) {aa};
\node   (bb) {bb};
\node   (cc) {cc};
%
\node   [suspend join,
         below=of aa] (dd) {cc};
\node   (ee) {ee};
\node   (ff) {ff};
    \end{scope}
\coordinate[right=of cc] (aux1);
\coordinate[ left=of dd] (aux2);
\draw[arr]  (cc) -- (aux1) |-| (aux2) -- (dd);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer